# Apple Hardware Accessories or third-party?

Tags: keyboard, usb, hardware, hardware-recommendation, optical-drive

I am running MacBook Air 13"

I need wireless keyboard, which I am going to use daily. Once in a while, I need to check some CDs or DVDs - mostly I take backup of photos shoot with camera and phone on CDs, so also planning to buy portable DVD and CD writer, which can work with MacBook Air.

Apple has both hardware available

1. Apple Wireless Keyboard - [link](http://www.apple.com/in/keyboard/)
2. Apple USB SuperDrive - [link](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD564LL/A/apple-usb-superdrive)

As you must be knowing, MacBook Air only has 1 USB port on each side, and lot of external DVD and CD writes comes with 2-usb cable. I am not taking about wireless CD/DVD writer, only USB writer.

I need your suggestion for both - keyboard and writer.

Should I go ahead and buy Apple ones, or are there better h/w available in market which is compatible with MacBook Air?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using the Apple Bluetooth keyboard for ~ 5 years, and I am pretty happy with it. It is pretty sturdy and even after such long time and ~8 hrs daily usage, I wouldn't notice any significant sign of wear. One advantage is that it is the same keyboard layout as on the MacBooks, which may be more convenient when switching back and forth between the external and in-built keyboard. A disadvantage is that it doesn't have background illumination, but it only really matters if you work in a rather dark environment. 
I also saw a logitech keyboard at a Best Buy once which looked almost exactly like the Apple Bluetooth keyboard, except that it was plastic, not aluminum; the price was about the same, and it also almost felt like the same; however, I can't say anything about its long-term durability.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I spilled water over it a couple of times, and one time it was half a glass of coke. I turned it off, took out the batteries, and put it under running water in my sink for about 10 minutes (I was afraid that it'd be sticky if it would still work at all afterwards). Next, I let it dry for about 1 1/2 weeks and used a spare mechanical keyboard instead (which I really love too). However, the Apple Bluetooth keyboard turned out to be fine eventually.

Sorry, I can't really comment on the CD/DVD drive: I haven't used any for a decade or so.

Comment: thanks. I don't need background illumination. So, I guess I will prefer Apple wireless keyboard.

BTW I was taking about USB external drive, not wireless CD/DVD drive.